# Asserting a callback Action was executed with nUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a class that has 2 callback actions:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void DoSomething(Action onSuccess, Action onFailure)
    { }
}
```

I'm trying to write a test for this, but not sure how to 'assert' that my `onSuccess` was executed?

```
[Test]
public void ChangePassword_returns_false_if_user_does_not_exist()
{
    var myClass = new MyClass(mockedDependency.Object);

    myClass.DoSomething( //what do i need to pass in, in order to Assert that onSuccess Action was executed?)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create action which changes some flag:

```
[Test]
public void ChangePassword_returns_false_if_user_does_not_exist()
{
    var myClass = new MyClass(mockedDependency.Object);
    bool isExecuted = false; // flag to check
    Action success = () => isExecuted = true; // set flag to true when executed

    myClass.DoSomething(success, null);
    Assert.IsTrue(isExecuted); // check if flag changed
}
```

Or even use in-place lambda to change flag:

```
[Test]
public void ChangePassword_returns_false_if_user_does_not_exist()
{
    var myClass = new MyClass(mockedDependency.Object);
    bool isExecuted = false; // flag to check
    myClass.DoSomething(() => isExecuted = true, null);
    Assert.IsTrue(isExecuted); // check if flag changed
}
```

---

One more approach - you can use Moq to verify if action was called or not. In this case you will not need any flags. First you would need some interface with methods matching `Action` delegate signature:

```
public interface IHelper // consider better name
{
    void ShouldRun();
    void ShouldNotRun();
}
```

Then you can use mock to verify times actions was called:

```
[Test]
public void ChangePassword_returns_false_if_user_does_not_exist()
{
    Mock<IHelper> helper = new Mock<IHelper>();            
    var myClass = new MyClass(ockedDependency.Object);
    myClass.DoSomething(helper.Object.ShouldRun, helper.Object.ShouldNotRun);

    helper.Verify(h => h.ShouldRun(), Times.Once());
    helper.Verify(h => h.ShouldNotRun(), Times.Never());
}
```